# Show that if the height of a prime ideal is zero, then it is a prime ideal belonging to 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

I was reading Atiyah-Macdonald p. 122, the proof of the Krull's principal ideal theorem:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and let $x$ be an element of $A$ which is neither a zero-divisor nor a unit. Then every minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $(x)$ has height $1$.
>
> *Proof.* First we have height $\mathfrak{p}\leq 1$. If height $\mathfrak{p}=0$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal belonging to $0$, hence every element of $\mathfrak{p}$ is a zero divisor: contradiction, since $x\in \mathfrak{p}$.

I don't know how to show that

> If height $\mathfrak{p}=0$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal belonging to $0$.

Any hints and answer are welcome!

---

However, I have an alternative proof: If height $\mathfrak{p}=0$, then $\dim A_\mathfrak{p}=0$ and therefore $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a local Artin ring. Thus, $(\mathfrak{p}^e)^n=0$ for some $n$, which implies that every element of $\mathfrak{p}$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: The claim is pretty obvious: a prime ideal of height 0 is minimal; now consider a primary decomposition of (0) and recall that every prime ideal contains (0).

Comment: @user26857 thanks for your comment! It is still not obvious to me right now. Could you write more details or an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by a prime ideal belonging to 0?

Comment: @user26857 if we have the primary decomposition of 0, say 0 is the intersection of some primary ideals, then their radicals are the prime ideals belonging to 0.

Comment: Good. And our minimal prime contains one of the primary ideals in the decomposition of (0). Then it contains its radical, which is prime, and from minimality are equal.

Comment: @user26857 I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noetherian case: Let $p$ be a minimal prime ideal of $R$ and let $0=q_1\cap\cdots \cap q_n$ be a primary decomposition of the zero ideal. Hence $q_1\cap\cdots\cap q_n\subseteq p$ and thus $\sqrt{q_1\cap\cdots\cap q_n}\subseteq p$. Hence we have $\sqrt{q_1}\cap\cdots\cap \sqrt{q_n}\subseteq p$ and so there is an $i$ such that $\sqrt{q_i}\subseteq p$. Now since $p$ is a minimal prime ideal, we have $\sqrt{q_i}=p$. So $p\in \mathrm{Ass}(R)$ and every element of $p$ is a zerodivizor since $Z(R)=\cup_{q\in \mathrm{Ass}(R)} q$.

General case: It is well-known a prime ideal $p$ is minimal prime if and only if for each $x\in p$ there exists $y\in R\setminus p$ such that $xy$ is nilpotent. This shows that every element of a minimal prime ideal is a zero divizor.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to show in the *general case*. The OP wants to show that a minimal prime is associated. Or in general, this isn't true. Eventually can replace associated by weakly associated.